# Note taking applications when learning about programming?

Tags: evernote

When I am learning about programming I use:

- **XMind** to create concise mind maps of the concepts I am learning
- **Evernote** to take notes in the form of bullet lists
- **Brackets** to save important code snippets

Is there one tool that does all of these things?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

You can maybe take a look at https://www.moh.io/mohiomap/app.php as it renders your evernote notes in a mindmap-style interface.

Might be useful.

(I do not work for moh.io)